# Expressing ideas directly in code - what does the definition mean?

Tags: c++, cpp-core-guidelines

Im new to c++, I'm reading the core guidelines and I came across this:

P.1: Express ideas directly in code

In this, it says to use something like `Month month() const;` instead of `int month();`

So I have 2 questions, why is there a const at the end of the function and what does that do? And how is Month defined? Can you declare new functions with any name instead of things like int, double, float etc?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you should start off with the basics first before reading the core guidelines.  The questions you've asked are covered in any good C++ book.

Comment: The `const` means the method promises not to alter the state of the object.  The Month could be defined as`enum class Month : int {};`

Comment: The trailing `const` only makes sense if the function is a member of a class, and in that case the `const` is a promise enforced by the compiler (ie the program will not compile if the function tries to change the instance)  that the function will not modify the class instance on which the function was called.

Comment: The rest we have to guess at. Could be because of many things.

Comment: *Can you declare new functions with any name instead of things like int, double, float etc?* In general, yes, so long as the name has previously been declared (and defined in this case as it's [returning by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value) and must know how to make a copy).

Comment: Side note: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Take the guidelines with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 6):

The point of the guideline is what it says: to put the ideas behind the interface in the code itself.

If you have some date type, and it has a member function `int month();`, that expresses the idea that you can retrieve a month from the date. And presumably, the returned `int` value represents the month of the year as stored within that date.

But... how does it represent the month? It's an integer. Is the month of January given the integer 0, as might be expected by a long-time programmer (of most languages)? Or maybe it is given the integer 1, because that's how dates are actually written? The code *itself* says nothing about this; you would have to look at the documentation for the function to find out. So if you see `if(date.month() == 1)`, you don't know if the code is asking if it is January or February.

The alternative, `Month month() const;` returns the type `Month`. Now, what that type is is not specified. Whatever it is, that type can make it unambiguous what value is represented by "January". For example:

```
enum class Month { January, February, ...};
```

How is "January" encoded? By the enum value `Month::January`. Therefore,  if you see the test `if(data.month() == Month::January)`, then it is clear *exactly* what it is saying. It is not only unambiguous, it also reads almost exactly like English: is the month of the date the month of January.

This is what it means to express an idea in the code: the *entirety* of the idea is unambiguously expressed by the code. Make the code say *what* it is doing, not-so-much *how* it is doing it.